# How to store logistic regression parameters once trained (SKlearn)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have a quick question here. I am using a simple logistic regression model for prediction.

Below is the code I've built.

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn import linear_model

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

df_raw = pd.read_csv('\\Users\\rapha\\Desktop\\Consulting\\Poker\\Tables test\\Final model\\SB Allpro DB - a4_flop.csv', sep=";")




#Select categorical features only & use binary encoding



feature_cols1 = ['tiers','score','tiers3_theory','tiers2_theory',
                 'proba2_preflop','proba_preflop','proba_flop',
                 
                 'best_hand_flop','checker_flop',
                 'action1_preflop','action2_preflop','action3_preflop','action4_preflop',
                 'action1_flop','action2_flop','action3_flop','action4_flop',
                 'Betaction1_preflop','Betaction2_preflop','Betaction3_preflop','Betaction4_preflop',
                 'Betaction1_flop','Betaction2_flop','Betaction3_flop']



df_raw = df_raw[feature_cols1]
df_backup = df_raw['action4_flop']
cat_features = df_raw.select_dtypes(include=[object])

num_features = df_raw.select_dtypes(exclude=[object])
num_features = num_features.drop(['action4_flop'], axis=1)
df = num_features.join(pd.get_dummies(cat_features))
df = df.join(df_backup)



df_outcome = df.action4_flop
df_variables_mid = df.drop('action4_flop',axis=1)


col_names = list(df_variables_mid.columns)
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df_variables_minmax = scaler.fit_transform(df_variables_mid)
df_variables = pd.DataFrame(df_variables_minmax,columns = col_names)

x = df_variables
y = df.action4_flop


x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=1)

lm = linear_model.LogisticRegression(multi_class='ovr', solver='liblinear', max_iter=1000)
lm.fit(x_train, y_train)



predict_test=lm.predict(x_test)
```

So everytime I run the notebook, I get my model trained and then I'm able to make predictions using the `.prediction`.

Is there anyway I could run my notebook again while not re-training the model? (could I store somewhere the parameters of the train model so I could only use the prediction function while not training the model again?)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Use can use joblib which is the best way to save your trained model. You can also save your "weights" in a text file. You could also do it with python pickle moduel (the way I prefer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [joblib dump/load](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.dump.html)

```
import joblib

...

filename = 'model.bin'
joblib.dump(model, filename)
 
...
 
restored_model = joblib.load(filename)
result = restored_model.predict(x_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides joblib, **pickle** is also a common choice to serialise the model.

```
import pickle
# save the model using pickle
model_name = 'trained_model.sav'
pickle.dump(lm, open(model_name, 'wb'))


# load the saved model from disk 
model = pickle.load(open(model_name, 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.score(x_test, y_test)
```